# "Pull" files from other GIT branch

Tags: git, version-control

The question arises from process of developing multiple products which are very similar, and core changes must be pushed to all of its versions.

### Short question:

**What can be used for getting the files from other GIT branch?**
(for example, as `git pull` could be used to get commits, alternative for *custom files* is needed)

### Long question:

GIT Hierarchy being the following:

```
master  
|── product-A  
└── product-B
```

Some changes (commits) are made on *product-A* branch, and on *product-B* we want make changes mostly based on those of *product-A*.
**What are the options of transferring the code written on one branch to another without pulling the commits, as it might not make sense to have *product-A*-specific commits in *product-B* ?**

Ideally:

- I would expect ability to resolve issues (behavior similar to resolving the code conflicts as with `git mergetool`)
- Solution which would work also if files are in another repository of a very similar product (is there anything better than copying and pasting files?)

Comment: Would making those "core" changes on parent-branch in first place help?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
# get your files
git cherry-pick -n <commit>

# unstage changes
git reset

# select the changes you need
git add -p

# commit
git commit
```

or commit your changes to the parent branch as Evusas sugested

Answer (score 0):

**Transferring changes from product-A branch to product-B branch**, you can use:

```
git checkout product-B
git cherry-pick <commit from product-A> -X theirs|ours
```

`<commit from product-A>` is the commit on `product-A` branch which contains the changes you want to transfer.

`-X` options, can solve the conflict files automatically. `-X theirs` will keeps the conflict files version as the commit on `product-A` you transferred. `-X ours` will keeps the conflict files version as current version on product-B branch.

**Transferring changes from one repo to another:**

```
# in the current git repo
git remote add another <URL for another repo> -f
gitk --all # find the commit on another/product-A branch which you want to transfer changes
git checkout product-B
git cherry-pick <the commit you found>
```